# how to change the src of an img tag dynamically in winjs app

Tags: html, image, winjs, src

I am developing Windows 8 store app using HTML5/JavaScript.
Looks simple, but I am not able to change the src of an image tag dynamically.

I am trying to bind an image in local storage and then change dynamically to another image in local storage on some event.

here is my HTML code and in javascript code on an event, i am trying to update src attribute.

```
<img class="peopleitem-image" id="profilePicture" src="ms-appdata:///local/ProfilePicture.jpg">

WinJS.UI.processAll().done(function () {
    document.getElementById("profilePicture").src = "ms-appdata:///local/ProfilePicture1.jpg";
});
```

is there anything I am missing..

Comment: Except for the odd looking URL, that is how you change the `.src` property of an image.  Are you sure that the image exists and has `id="profilePicture"` and it's in your current document?

Comment: yeah, image exists with the ID.
But the URL, its how we specify the resource in local local storage in Win8 Store apps.

Comment: The code looks correct using ms-appdata:///local/. Is the first image showing up correctly before you attempt to change it? (Also make sure the img element is self-closed, i.e. has /> at the end.) It should be noted that when an app is first installed, its /local appdata will be empty so any declarative reference in HTML to ms-appdata:///local/ would not resolve to anything until you programmatically created that image file.

Comment: thanks Kraig.
Yeah, first image loads correctly.
However, I changed the img to div and set background dynamically and it works fine now. thanks you.

    var url = "ms-appdata:///local//DefaultPicture1.jpg";
    url = { path: "url('" + url + "')" };
    var personDiv = element.querySelector("#divProfileImage");
    WinJS.Binding.processAll(personDiv, url);

below is the code.

Answer (score 0):

you can dynamically set picture by below jquery.

```
$("#profilePicture").attr({ "src": "your path" });
```

Comment: The usual practice here on SO is that you don't offer an answer using jQuery or any other library unless that library is specifically mentioned by the OP.  Plus, what you're offering here does nothing better than the plain JS code the OP already has so jQuery here is offering no unique value either.